# How to scroll from one edit text to another when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've been working on this note app where I have two **editTexts**, one for the title and one for the note content but for some reason, when there is a keyboard on the screen and the text is very long I can't scroll from say the note content **editText** to the title **editText**. I have added one **scrollView** for each and one for the layout but it still doesn't work.
Though the **editTexts** scroll just fine when there is no keyboard, how can I make it scroll when there is one?
Below is the screenshot of my problem[image]
`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context=".screens.newnotescreen.NewNoteFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/title_inputlayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:paddingStart="8dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
                        app:hintEnabled="false"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/note_title_edittext"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:hint="@string/title"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textImeMultiLine"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6" />

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/content_inputlayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:paddingStart="8dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                        app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
                        app:hintEnabled="false"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_inputlayout"> 
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/note_content_edittext"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:enabled="true"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:hint="@string/note"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:isScrollContainer="true"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1" />

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Comment: show your xml code please

Comment: Currently, my PC is not available to me but will make the edit once it's available

Comment: Try adding in Manifest to your activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" or android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: @CodeDexter I added the xml

Answer (score 0):

Add in AndroidManifest.xml for your activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**OR**

and under the onCreateView() method of the fragment `NewNoteFragment` do this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks. But, I've added this in my manifest.W hat I want though, is to scroll to the title edittext from the noteContent edittext manually while I'm entering the text